# How do you insert a newline in an Azure App Service app setting?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

In an Azure App Service web app, how do you insert a newline character (ie. \n) into an app setting using the Azure portal?  Using `\n` doesn't appear to get escaped like it would be in C#/json/etc.

If it's not possible, what is the recommended way to configure long strings of text to pass into an app?  We're also using continuous integration in Visual Studio Team Services and would prefer to not get into text transformations during the build process.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Azure application settings trim spaces automatically, so if you have spaces / newlines that need to be there as prefix or suffix with pipeline deployment, you will need to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think the Portal supports doing this. However, you should be able to do it via API. e.g. try this:

- Go to Resource Explorer (https://resources.azure.com/)
- Find your app (aka website), either using search box or by finding it in the tree
- Under your app, go to config/appsettings
- Click Edit (you may need to switch to Read/Write mode at the top)
- Add an App Setting with a new line, e.g. `"test": "1234\n5678"`
- Click POST

Comment: This is brilliant, didn't know about the Resource Explorer. Can confirm this approach doesn't escape newline characters in settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through Azure PowerShell task, but just remain newline symbol, the value won’t be in multiple lines, for example:

```
$webAppName="XXX"
$resourceGroupName="XXX"
$newAppSettings =@{"newSetting01"="newValue01";"newSetting02"="t1\nt2\n123456"}
Set-AzureRmWebApp -AppSettings $newAppSettings -Name $webAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

There is an article about update application setting: [Apply / Update application settings for Azure App Service using PowerShell](https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/02/26/apply-update-application-settings-for-azure-app-service-using-powershell/)